# trending or mean reverting using statsmodels.tsa.stattools

Tags: regression, mean, p-value, trending, reverting

most of the code below has been "gathered" from various sources.  the ultimate goal is to define a stock's closing price as either mean reverting or trending on as quick a timeframe as possible.  the hope is that this question and answer(s) can serve as a comphrensive look at the subject.  unfortunately, the output is confusing to me / conflicting.

section 1:  based on the p-value, this looks trending.  based on the critical values, this looks mean reverting.

section 2:  all trending except for lag at 50.  why is this one mean reverting?

section 3:  all trending.  these p-values are all over the place.  how does one know which 'type' to use?  does the raw data graph need to be analyzed to see the trending?  isn't the whole point of this to TELL us if this is trending?

section 4:  all trending, except (lag, autolag) = (20, t-stat), (30, t-stat), (40, t-stat), (50, AIC).  why?

section 5:  strongly mean reverting.  all benchmarks look close.

section 6:  why are there multiple half life values?  which one is right?

thanks.

input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts # time series library
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import statsmodels.api as sm
from numpy import cumsum, log, polyfit, sqrt, std, subtract
from numpy.random import randn

#............................
df = wb.DataReader('GE','google', '2003, 5, 1', '2003, 12, 15')

print ('\n....... section 1 - adf statistic ......................')
name = pd.Series (df['Close'].values)
result = adfuller (name)

print('close - adf statistic: %f' % result[0] + ', p value: %f' % result[1])

if result[1] > 0.05:
    print ('trending based on p value > 0.05')
else:
    print ('mean reverting based on p value < 0.05')

print('critical values:')

for key, value in result[4].items():
    print('\t%s: %.3f' % (key, value))
    print ('if adf statistic > % test statistic, then trending at that %')

print ('\n..... section 2 - different lag times ...................')

lag_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

for lag in lag_list:
    name = pd.Series (df['Close'].values)
    result = adfuller (name, maxlag = lag)
    if result[1] > 0.05:
        print ('p-value: %f' % result[1] + ' trending based on lag = ' + str(lag))
    else:
        print ('p-value: %f' % result[1] + ' mean reverting based on lag = ' + str(lag))

print ('\n..... section 3 - different regression types ..........')
regress_list = ['c','ct','ctt','nc']

for regress in regress_list:
    name = pd.Series (df['Close'].values)
    result = adfuller (name, regression = regress)

    if regress == 'c':
        print ('regression for close with ' + regress + ' = constant only, p-value: %f' % result[1])
    if regress == 'ct':
        print ('\nregression for close with ' + regress + ' = constant and trend, p-value: %f' % result[1])
    if regress == 'ctt':
        print ('\nregression for close with ' + regress + ' = constant and linear and quadratic trend, p-value: %f' % result[1])
    if regress == 'nc':
        print ('\nregression for close with ' + regress + ' = no constant, no trend, p-value: %f' % result[1])    

    if result[1] > 0.05:
        print ('trending based on p value > 0.05')
    else:
        print ('mean reverting based on p value < 0.05')

print ('\n......... section 4 - different lag types')

alag_list = ['AIC', 'BIC', 't-stat'] 

for lag in lag_list:
    for alag in alag_list:
        name = pd.Series (df['Close'].values)
        result = adfuller (name, maxlag = lag, autolag = alag)
        print ('\nlag = ' + str(lag) + ', autolag = ' + alag + ', p-value = %f' % result[1])
        if result[1] > 0.05:
            print ('trending based on p value > 0.05')
        else:
            print ('mean reverting based on p value < 0.05')

print ('\n........ section 5 - hurst..........................')
def hurst(ts): # Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts
    lags = range(2, 100) # Create the range of lag values

    # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1) # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
    return poly[0]*2.0 # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output

gbm = log(cumsum(randn(100000))+1000) # geometric brownian motion
mr = log(randn(100000)+1000) # mean reverting
tr = log(cumsum(randn(100000)+1)+1000) # trending

# Output the Hurst Exponent for each of the above series and the price of the ticker's close for the ADF test 
print ("hurst - geometric brownian motion - random walk - should be around 0.50:   %s" % hurst(gbm))
print ("hurst - mean reverting - should be around 0.00):    %s" % hurst(mr))
print ("hurst - trending - should be around 1.00):    %s" % hurst(tr))
print ("hurst:  %s" % hurst(df['Close']))

print ('\n.......  section 6 - half life ..........................')

def get_halflife(s):
    s_lag = s.shift(1)
    s_lag.ix[0] = s_lag.ix[1]

    s_ret = s - s_lag
    s_ret.ix[0] = s_ret.ix[1]

    s_lag2 = sm.add_constant(s_lag)

    model = sm.OLS(s_ret,s_lag2)
    res = model.fit()

    halflife = round(-np.log(2) / res.params[1],0)
    print ('half life = ' + str(halflife))
    return halflife

df.apply(get_halflife)
print ('\nprogram complete')
```

output:

```
.................... section 1 - adf statistic ......................
close - adf statistic: -1.959732, p value: 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05
critical values:
    5%: -2.880
if adf statistic > % test statistic, then trending at that %
    10%: -2.577
if adf statistic > % test statistic, then trending at that %
    1%: -3.472
if adf statistic > % test statistic, then trending at that %

.................. section 2 - different lag times ...................
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 1
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 2
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 3
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 4
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 5
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 6
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 7
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 8
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 9
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 10
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 20
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 30
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 40
p-value: 0.009252 mean reverting based on lag = 50
p-value: 0.304504 trending based on lag = 60

.......... section 3 - different regression types ....................
regression for close with c = constant only, p-value: 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

regression for close with ct = constant and trend, p-value: 0.588526
trending based on p value > 0.05

regression for close with ctt = constant and linear and quadratic trend, p-
value: 0.817117
trending based on p value > 0.05

regression for close with nc = no constant, no trend, p-value: 0.739828
trending based on p value > 0.05

........................ section 4 - different lag types

lag = 1, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 1, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 1, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 2, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 2, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 2, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 3, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 3, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 3, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 4, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 4, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 4, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 5, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 5, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 5, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 6, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 6, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 6, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 7, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 7, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 7, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 8, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 8, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 8, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 9, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 9, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 9, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 10, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 10, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 10, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 20, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 20, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 20, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.046194
mean reverting based on p value < 0.05

lag = 30, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504  
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 30, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 30, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.009252
mean reverting based on p value < 0.05

lag = 40, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 40, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 40, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.009252
mean reverting based on p value < 0.05

lag = 50, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.009252
mean reverting based on p value < 0.05

lag = 50, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 50, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.335375
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 60, autolag = AIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 60, autolag = BIC, p-value = 0.304504
trending based on p value > 0.05

lag = 60, autolag = t-stat, p-value = 0.335375
trending based on p value > 0.05

................ section 5 - hurst..........................
hurst - geometric brownian motion - random walk - should be around 0.50:   0.50270119846
hurst - mean reverting - should be around 0.00):    0.000107190651568
hurst - trending - should be around 1.00):    0.95085392982 
hurst:  0.114851328923

..................  section 6 - half life ..........................
half life = 15.0
half life = 11.0
half life = 10.0
half life = 14.0
half life = 1.0

program complete
```

Comment: comments on section 5:  this paper, http://mosaic.mpi-cbg.de/docs/Racine2011.pdf, indicates that the minimum length for meaningful results is at least 2^6 = 64 observations.  these are the results of similar tests (# observations, hurst) = (100, 0.11), (64, 0.29), (32, 0.53), (16, 0.55), (8, 0.55).  this does not appear to be a good short term test

Comment: comments on section 6:  another code formulation was discovered for the half life calculation.  it appears that the multiple half life answers are for each column in the df = OHLCV.

Comment: comments on section 1:  it appears that i misunderstood the p-value completely.  after some research, it appears the way to explain the answer is that 70% of the time the data is mean reverting.  for the other 30% of the time the data may be either mean reverting or trending.  if that is wrong, please let us know.

Comment: comments on section 3:  if you are interested, this paper http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/working_papers/papers/qed_wp_1227.pdf explains a lot.  it appears that seeing the graph will drastically help you determine which type to use.  with p-values this high, it appears that this analysis isn't worth much = inconclusive.